# How to use Android's AsyncTask to get all of my data through JSoup, then send that information to another class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I'm pretty new to developing in Android, but I understand that I cannot run `Jsoup.connect(url).get()` without some kind of thread as it is a synchronous call. I tried creating a class called Product that extends AsyncTask, and then having my original class called List call Product and then have the int displayed. However, regardless of the actual result, it always prints out 0.

I have tested my code before, so I know it works and that the issue must be something related to Android.

List Class:

```
public class List extends AppCompatActivity{
String itemURL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list_view);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

      Bundle itemData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(itemData==null){
        return;
    }

    //Gets URL
    itemURL = itemData.getString("itemURL");
    int listSize=new Product(itemURL).getListSize();
    System.out.println(listSize);
 }
}
```

Product class:

```
 public class Product extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    String url;
    String title;
    int listSize;


    public Product(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
    protected Void doInBackground (Void... voids) {
       //Create JSoup connection
        try{

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();
            //Gets title
            String link = doc.select("h2#s-result-count").first().text();
            System.out.println(link);
            listSize=Integer.parseInt(link.substring(0,1));
            System.out.println(listSize);
            try{
                int listSize= Integer.parseInt(link.substring(0,2));
                System.out.println(listSize);
               }catch(Exception e){}
         }catch (Exception e){}
    }


      protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            getListSize();


        }

       public int getListSize(){
        return listSize;
     }
}
```

All advice would be appreciated, thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Try following code

    Product product = new Product(itemURL);
    product.execute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override

```
onPostExecute()
```

to make sure you are getting the variable after it is updated from the thread.  Call your

```
getListSize()
```

from inside the overridden function.

Consider that calling

```
execute()
```

and then immediately calling

```
getListSize()
```

will happen line by line while the actual thread you have spun off will continue working.  You're asking for a value that hasn't been updated.

Edit::

For clarification:

```
public class List extends AppCompatActivity{
    String itemURL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Bundle itemData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(itemData==null){
            return;
        }

        //Gets URL
        itemURL = itemData.getString("itemURL");
        int listSize=new Product(itemURL).getListSize();  // this doesn't do anything meaningful for you
        System.out.println(listSize);
    }
}
```

Note the comment I have added to

> int listSize = new Product(itemURL).getListSize();

First,

> doInBackground()

will never run until you call

> execute()

You need to call

```
new Product(itemURL).execute();
```

Afterword, you have to provide some kind of callback to the Activity since you haven't nested the product class or initialized an anonymous instance of AsyncTask.

In your Product class you can set a variable

> Context

```
public class Product extends AsyncTask<...> {
    public Context context;
}
```

Then, in place of

> int listSize = new Product(itemURL).getListSize();

put:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.context = this;
product.execute();
```

Then, in Product's

> onPostExecute()

put:

```
if (context.getClass().equals(List.class)) {
    ((List) context).some_method_that_does_something_with_list_size()
}
```

Alternatively, you can add it to Product's constructor:

```
public Product(String url, Context context) {...}
```

Edit 2::

For further clarification

> ((List) context).some_method_that_does_something_with_list_size()

was meant to serve as a placemarker for any method available in your activity.  It could easily be substituted with:

```
System.out.println(listSize);
```

Edit 3::

For further, further clarification:

In your Activity, ItemListView, define a method called

```
printListSize(int listSize) {
    System.out.println("list size: " + listSize);
}
```

Then, in onPostExecute() call:

```
((ItemListView) context).printListSize(listSize);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I fully understood everything you suggested. I have overriden onPostExecute() and updated the code above to reflect that. What should I do now?

Comment: On the last step, if I try to call ((List) context).getListSize() it doens't work, presumably because we're typecasting it as a List and List doesn't have getListSize but Product does. Am I doing something wrong or thinking about it in the wrong way?

Comment: You've imported incorrectly, then.  You should not have named your activity List

Comment: You can give the fully qualified named to your activity, if you want.  The compiler will do this for you if you select suggestions on your error line

Comment: I changed the name to something that wouldn't possibly give any errors but I'm still having that problem

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Replace "some_method_that_does_something_with_list_size()" with a method from your activity, or just print the value of list size.

Comment: But I want to print the value in the List class, but in the Product's onPostExecute when I write:
   if (context.getClass().equals(ItemListView.class)) {
            ((ItemListView) context).getListSize();

        }

it gives me an error

Comment: That's because "getListSize()" is a method of the Product class, not ItemListView.  You have to have a method available in your activity

Comment: I have edited my answer for even further clarification

Comment: Okay, thanks, I understand that now. Unfortunately, now I'm getting an error that says:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Comment: At what line are you getting the error? The number won't help me, tell me the line's codem

Comment: This is popping up on the if statement in the onPostExecute method by the way
 if (context.getClass().equals(ItemListView.class)) {
            ((ItemListView) context).printListSize(getListSize());

        }

Comment: The only possible problem is that context is null. Are you sure you set in when you initialized Product as shown in my answer?
Product product = new Product(url);
product.context = this;

Comment: Yes, I did that but it appears to not have worked. I tried your alternate method of adding it through the constructor and that worked beautifully though. Everything's finally up and running, thank you for sticking with me for an hour haha.

Comment: No problem. Threading can be a very, very difficult concept, especially for anybody new to it.  You'll get there.  Good luck with your future programming adeventures!

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing, what exactly do .execute() and onPostExecute() do, and why didn't my code run properly without those two and the if statement?

Comment: That's a difficult thing to explain concisely. Most code you write runs on the same thread, so everything thing flows logically, line by line, the way you read it. When you thread a function it run on a different timeline. Meaning, the task may not have finished, thus the variable may not update, by the time you request it. .execute() runs on a new thread. .onPostExecute() is a callback for when the thread is finished. This lets you know that the work is done and your variable is updated.

Comment: The if statement was just there as good practice. Your code will run without it.

Comment: Okay, that's starting to make a lot of sense now. Thanks for all your help!